# How to allow numbers only using f:validateRegex

Tags: regex, validation, jsf

I've an input which should allow numbers only. I tried adding `<f:validateRegex>` as follows:

```
<f:validateRegex pattern="[0-9]" />
```

But I still get the error message,

> Validation Error: Value not according to pattern '[0-9]'

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The pattern `[0-9]` allows input of a **single** digit only. Perhaps you want input of multiple digits? In that case, you should use a pattern of `[0-9]+`. The `+` modifier namely means "one or more".

```
<f:validateRegex pattern="[0-9]+" />
```

If you allow empty input, then use the `*` modifier instead which means "zero or more".

```
<f:validateRegex pattern="[0-9]*" />
```

#### See also:

- [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) - the premier website about regular expressions